# Graphics from ScrollViewer overlays graphics outside ScrollViewer when scrolled down (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, drawing

I have a XAML file. In this XAML file I have a `ScrollViewer` to which later I add `WinFormsHost` -> basically place where you can put standard `WinForm`. When I scroll the `ScrollViewer` down the graphics from inside of it goes outside. Please look at the first an the second screenshot. **How to deal with that drawing problem? Can I set ZIndex for that `ScrollViewer`?**

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example" 
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="Window_Loaded"

        >

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!-- this column is for future purpouses -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1366" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                <ListBox x:Name="ListBox"   
                </ListBox>
            </Border>
            <Button x:Name="AcceptButton" Grid.Row="1" ></Button>
        </Grid>  
        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" >
                <WrapPanel x:Name="WinFormsPanel" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                </WrapPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>   
    </Grid>   
</Window>
```

### **AT THE BEGINNING**

[image]

---

### **SCROLLED DOWN - WHEN SCROLLED UP EVERYTHING GOES BACK TO NORMAL**

[image]

**EDIT ** Tried, but no difference:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ClipToBounds="True">
            <ScrollViewer ClipToBounds="True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" >
                <WrapPanel ClipToBounds="True" x:Name="VideoPanel" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                </WrapPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
```

EDIT 2:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="HomeSecurity.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HomeSecurity" 
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
            <ScrollViewer >
                <WrapPanel x:Name="VideoPanel" >
                </WrapPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**MAINWINDOW.XAML.CS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace HomeSecurity {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            add(); add(); add();
        }

        private void add() {


            WindowsFormsHost formsHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
            VideoStream videoStream = new VideoStream();
            formsHost.Width = 400;
            formsHost.Height = 400;
            formsHost.Child = videoStream;
            Border lineBorder = new Border();
            lineBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
            lineBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
            lineBorder.Child = formsHost;
            VideoPanel.Children.Add(lineBorder);
        }
    }
}
```

There has to be added reference to `System.WindowsFormsIntegration`, `System.Windows.Forms`, `System.Drawing`.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have some problem there and you should thoroughly investigate what is going on with your code to try to rectify the situation optimally. However, the code that you have shown here is not to blame. I tried it in a new project and it works as expected. As there is nothing inside the `WrapPanel`, there is no content in the `ScrollViewer` to cause your problem.  When adding code to demonstrate a problem, you should ensure that your code *does* demonstrate the problem.

Even so, without being able to recreate your problem, there *might* just be a quick fix that you can use in this case. You can just set the [`UIElement.ClipToBounds` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `Border` to `True` and this will clip anything that extends beyond its bounds.

```
<Border ClipToBounds="True" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" ...>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" >
        <WrapPanel x:Name="WinFormsPanel" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
        </WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Comment: Unfortunately `ClipToBounds` didn't change the behaviour. PLease look at the edit of original post.

Comment: When I suggested that you edit your post to ensure that your code *does* demonstrate the problem, I didn't mean that you should add text telling people to manually change the code themselves... I meant that *you* should do that. If you provide a complete working sample that demonstrates your problem, then you will surely get more help. Users here want to be able to quickly paste a code example into a test project and [some may] get put off if they have to manually edit it.

Comment: Working sample added.

Comment: I gave your code another go, but still can't see any problems. Maybe it's down to that `VideoStream` class, which doesn't seem to be from Windows and which I couldn't get to work?

Comment: Yes. Now I deleted `VideoStream()` from the sample code I provided. The `VideoStream()` is a `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` containing an `Activex`(COM) element called `AxAcisMediaControl` which belongs to the `Axis SDK`. Inside that element there is a video displayed from local network camera. If I delete this `Activex Control` problem dissapears. -> But I need that control, it handles displaying and connecting to the specified URL, recording, taking snapshots. http://www.axis.com/techsup/cam_servers/dev/activex.htm

Comment: I have an idea. The graphics is displayed correctly when the window is minimized and then maximized. There is probably something like `repaint()` called. Do you know how to invoke `repaint()` when the scrollbar is used?

Comment: @user3196085, if you have another question, then please ask a new question and provide a link to this question in it. At StackOverflow, we prefer each post to contain just one main question and one accepted answer and as your new question is so different, it warrants being posted as a new question. It would also attract more attention. Thanks.